# Why does terraformer not find plugin?

Tags: windows, terraform, chocolatey, terraform-provider-gcp

I am new to the world of terraform. I am trying to use terraformer on a GCP project, but keep getting plugin not found:

```
terraformer import google --resources=gcs,forwardingRules,httpHealthChecks --connect=true --
regions=europe-west1,europe-west4 --projects=myproj
2021/02/12 08:17:03 google importing project myproj region europe-west1
2021/02/12 08:17:04 google importing... gcs
2021/02/12 08:17:05 open \.terraform.d/plugins/windows_amd64: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Prior to the above, installed terraformer thus: `choco install terraformer` I downloaded the Google provider, `terraform-provider-google_v3.56.0_x5.exe`, placed it in my terraform dir, and did `terraform init`. I checked `%AppData\Roaming\terraform.d\plugins\windows_amd64` and the `plugins\windows_amd64` did not exist, so I created it, dropped in the Google exe and redid the init.

My main.tf was:

```
provider "google" {
 project = "{myproj"
  region  = "europe-west2"
  zone    = "europe-west2-a"
}
```

Could it be the chocolatey install causing this issue? I have never used it before but the alternative install looks daunting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The daunting instructions worked!

```
Run git clone <terraformer repo>
Run go mod download
Run go build -v for all providers OR build with one provider go run build/main.go {google,aws,azure,kubernetes and etc}
Run terraform init against an versions.tf file to install the plugins required for your platform. For example, if you need plugins for the google provider, versions.tf should contain:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
}
```

making sure to run that version and not the chocolatey one.

`go mod download` the flag **-x** will give output while that command runs, otherwise you might think nothing is happening.

Comment: I am also trying to use terraformer but getting error as `terraformer is not recognised as an internal or external command`.  So `terraformer import google....` these command have to be run on cmd after above steps , is that correct ? or do i have to add to some sort of env variable ?

Answer (score 7):

If you install from Chocolatey, it seems it looks for the provider files at `C:\.terraform.d\plugins\windows_amd64`. If you create those directories and drop the `terraform-provider-xxx.exe` file in there it will be picked up.

I would also suggest running it with the `--verbose` flag.

Answer (score 3):

Remember to execute "terraform init"

Once you install the terraformer, check this

- Create the versions.tf file
- versions.tf example

  ```
  terraform {
    required_providers {
      google = {
        source = "hashicorp/aws"
      }
    }
    required_version = ">= 0.13"
  }
  ```
- Execute terraform init
- Start the import process, something like:

  ```
  terraformer import aws --profile [my-aws-profile] --resources="*" --regions=eu-west-1
  ```

Where --resources="*" will get everything from aws, but you could specify route53 or other resources

```
terraformer import aws --profile [my-aws-profile] --resources="route53" --regions=eu-west-1
```